# User guide for Redux DevTools?

Tags: redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I'm trying to become a power user of the Redux DevTools, but I can't find any advanced guide for all the features. The GitHub README is just about the code involved in using it and setting it up.

Is there a guide somewhere to using **all** the features of the actual extension?

Answer (score -1):

The docs are here : https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension.
However, I found them a bit hard to understand.

I found the link below useful:
https://codeburst.io/redux-devtools-for-dummies-74566c597d7